# App stopping calls

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, phone-call

I have class `BaseActivity` that contains many Menu items, and `BaseActivity` is extended by all of my other activities so that those same menu items appear in all the activities that extend it. I want to mute my apps audio when the user gets a call, so I decided to put some more code into `BaseActivity` which mute the app when the user gets a call.

I have searched the web and found two ways, neither work though:

**First method I tried: (In Base Activity)**

```
PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                //Incoming call: Pause music

                TwentySeconds.stopTimer();
                Intent i = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, FinishedBeforeTimer.class);
                startActivity(i);

                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "INCOMING CALL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                //Not in call: Play music
            } else if(state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                //A call is dialing, active or on hold

                TwentySeconds.stopTimer();
                Intent i = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, FinishedBeforeTimer.class);
                startActivity(i);

                Toast.makeText(BaseActivity.this, "DIALING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

With this code in my BaseActivity,  when I call the my phone, the phone I am calling with says that I can't call my phone, and my phone never rings. That is very weird...

**Second Method I tried:**

I have also tried to use the intent as shown [here](http://karanbalkar.com/2014/02/detect-incoming-call-and-call-hangup-event-in-android/), but I cannot extend **both** appCompatAbility **and** BroadcastReceiver in my BaseActivity.

Why is my first method **blocking** calls? Also, if the second method is easier, how can I accomplish it, because multiple inheritance is impossible in android.

These are the two main ways I found after searching the web for over an hour, but there has to be another way! I would really appreciate your feedback as to why my methods are doing what they are doing, or as to how I can accomplish my task. I am always open to new things.

Comment: What is FinishedBeforeTimer.class? Do the activities ever open?

Comment: @napkinsterror `FinishedBeforeTimer.class` is just another activity that I want to display when the call gets made. No, the activities do not ever end up opening up. Also, the phone call doesn't get made

Comment: Do you have an AudioManager instance? `AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, true);`

Comment: From my understanding you have many activities. only one will be showing at a time. you have one audio source coming from your app. and you want to mute your app when a phone call is coming in? Knowing what you are trying to do with FinishedBeforeTimer might be good. Try to remove startActivity() from the code and see if your phone call goes through.

Comment: Also be sure to `Override the methods for the state that you wish to receive updates for, and pass your PhoneStateListener object, along with bitwise-or of the LISTEN_ flags to TelephonyManager.listen().`

Comment: @napkinsterror What will removing `startActivity()` do?

Comment: It might be the problem with the phone call not going through. You might be trying to start an activity when the phone is also trying to accomplish the same task.

Comment: @napkinsterror Oh, that makes sense. Let me try that! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94767/discussion-between-rich-and-napkinsterror).

Comment: @napkinsterror I am having a problem in my onPause. It gets called every time an activity switches, so it always mutes and stops telephoneymanager on every activity switch. How can I detect if the user left the app?